# How do I output a TABLE with names and scores with only using Arrays and Methods?

Tags: java, arrays

I have been trying to find the answer to this question but to no avail!
Basically I have to write a program where 'x' number of players can enter a guessing game and input their guesses and then get a score.

However, right after they input their guesses, i have to output it in a table form like this "NAME           GUESS  SCORE"

I do not know how i can do this with a for loop since a for loop println can only print values from playersArray. How can I print another array like guessesArray to the side of it?

I can only use Arrays and Methods to do this.

Below I will show u what i have right now:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.Math;
public class game
{   
static int[] guessesArray;
static int guess;
static String [] playersArray;
static int[] currscoresArray;
static int [] addscoresArray;
static int [] finalscoresArray;
 public static void main(String [] args){
   System.out.print("Number of players? ");
   Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
   int numplayers = kb.nextInt();


   //Initialize
   playersArray = new String[numplayers];
   guessesArray = new int [numplayers];

   currscoresArray = new int [numplayers];
   addscoresArray = new int [numplayers];
   finalscoresArray = new int [numplayers];

   populateArray(playersArray);
   displayMenu();
}

public static void populateArray( String[] x){
   Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i<x.length ; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter Player "+(i+1)+": ");
        x[i]=kb.nextLine();  
   }
}

public static void displayMenu(){
    int choice=0;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] args = {};
    while(true){
        System.out.println("Menu ");
        System.out.println("1. Make Guess");
        System.out.println("2. List Winner");
        System.out.println("0. Exit");
        System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
        choice = kb.nextInt();
        if (choice==0){
            System.out.print("Do you want to play a new game? Y/N: ");
            String ans = kb.next();
            if (ans.equals ("Y") || ans.equals ("y")){
                main(args);
            }
            break;
        } 

        switch (choice){
            case 1: makeGuess(); break;
            case 2: listWinner(); break;
            default: System.out.println("Invalid choice");
        }
    }
     System.out.println("End of program");System.exit(0);
}

public static void makeGuess(){   
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    int secret = rand.nextInt(10)+1;
    for (int i=0; i < guessesArray.length; i++){
       System.out.print("Enter your guess "+playersArray[i]+": ");
       guessesArray[i]=kb.nextInt();
    } 
    int diff = (int)(Math.abs(guess - secret));
    int score=0; 

    if (diff == 0){
        score=score+10;
    }else if(diff<=1){
        score=score+5;
    }else if(diff<=2){
        score=score+2;
    }
    for (int i=0; i< currscoresArray.length; i++){
        currscoresArray[i]=score;

    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Generated number is "+secret);
    System.out.println("Current Score Listing");
    System.out.println("     Name          Guess Score Added Final Score");
    System.out.println("1.   "+playersArray[0]+"     \t       "+guessesArray[0]+"  \t"+currscoresArray[0]+"");
    System.out.println("1.   "+playersArray[1]+"     \t      "+guessesArray[1]+"  \t"+currscoresArray[1]+"");
}

public static void listWinner(){
}
}
```

Comment: What kind of for-loop do you have in mind? If you know how to use indexed-for-loop then you just need to replace the "[0]" and "[1]" with the corresponding index variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just reuse a `int x` variable when printing from each array?

```
for( int x = 0; x < playersArray.length; x++ ) {
    System.out.println( playersArray[ x ] + ”    ” + guessArray[ x ] + "    " + finalScoresArray[ x ] );
}
```

you already give an example in your code where you print the 3 values with a single print method. you used a for loop for indexing an element in an array. So combing the 2 techniques shouldn't be too difficult to grasp.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an enhanced for loop (e.g. `for (String player : playersArray) {}`, you can use an indexed one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < playersArray.length; i++) {
    String name = playerArray[i];
    double score = scoresArray[i];
}
```

That being said, you should really make a Player class, that holds all information of a single player, and then have just one array, of that type. That's much nicer, not only because you can use enhanced fors, but because you don't need to make sure the arrays are always synced, and your code becomes way easier to understand.